# How to Dynamically display the image source and title for bootstrap cards?

Tags: javascript, html

I am really stuck here, i tried all the solutions provided on SO but not even a single one worked for me

I am trying to make a profile page and want to display content dynamically without php i tried dynamically creating an entire div along with json but it just didn't work (IT'S A CARD CAROUSEL SLIDER) i tried various method but i got only this one working [Using id to change the data using JS] i would appreciate if any one can help me out since i'am new to java i don't know much about it its becoming lengthy the way i am doing right now even if entire divs are displayed dynamically it will be much better since it will reduce the size of the overall script
[if any library is required i wouldn’t mind]

What i have tried

```js
/*---Cards Homepage---*/

/*---Card 1---*/
document.getElementById("ct1").innerHTML = "new title";
document.getElementById("ci1").innerHTML = "new image";

/*---Card 2---*/
document.getElementById("ct2").innerHTML = "new title";
document.getElementById("ci2").innerHTML = "new image";

/*---Card 3---*/
document.getElementById("ct3").innerHTML = "new title";
document.getElementById("ci3").innerHTML = "new image";

/*---Card 4---*/
document.getElementById("ct4").innerHTML = "new title";
document.getElementById("ci4").innerHTML = "new image";

/*---Card 5---*/
document.getElementById("ct5").innerHTML = "new title";
document.getElementById("ci5").innerHTML = "new image";

/*---Card 6---*/
document.getElementById("ct6").innerHTML = "new title";
document.getElementById("ci6").innerHTML = "new image";

/*---Card 7---*/
document.getElementById("ct7").innerHTML = "new title";
document.getElementById("ci7").innerHTML = "new image";

/*---Card 8---*/
document.getElementById("ct8").innerHTML = "new title";
document.getElementById("ci8").innerHTML = "new image";

/*---Card 9---*/
document.getElementById("ct9").innerHTML = "new title";
document.getElementById("ci9").innerHTML = "new image";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/homestyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/content.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vp86vTRFVJgpjF9jiIGPEEqYqlDwgyBgEF109VFjmqGmIY/Y4HV4d3Gp2irVfcrp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- CONTENT-->
  <section class="content">
    <div class="left-content">
      <div class="left-two">
        <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6">
                <h3 class="mb-3">Carousel cards title </h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 text-right">
                <a class="btn btn-dark mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-dark mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <div id="row-one" class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci1" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532763303805-529d595877c5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=5ee4fd5d19b40f93eadb21871757eda6">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct1" class="card-title">Image 1</h4>

                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci2" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532715088550-62f09305f765?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ebadb044b374504ef8e81bdec4d0e840">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct2" class="card-title">Image 2</h4>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci3" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506197603052-3cc9c3a201bd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=0754ab085804ae8a3b562548e6b4aa2e">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct3" class="card-title">Image 3</h4>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci4" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532771098148-525cefe10c23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3f317c1f7a16116dec454fbc267dd8e4">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct4" class="card-title">Image 4</h4>

                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci5" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532715088550-62f09305f765?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ebadb044b374504ef8e81bdec4d0e840">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct5" class="card-title">Image 5</h4>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci6" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506197603052-3cc9c3a201bd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=0754ab085804ae8a3b562548e6b4aa2e">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct6" class="card-title">Image 6</h4>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci7" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ee8417f0ea2a50d53a12665820b54e23">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct7" class="card-title">Image 7</h4>

                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci8" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532777946373-b6783242f211?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=8ac55cf3a68785643998730839663129">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct8" class="card-title">Image 8</h4>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci9" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532763303805-529d595877c5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=5ee4fd5d19b40f93eadb21871757eda6">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct9" class="card-title">Image 9</h4>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-content"></div>
  </section>

  <script src="./js/script.js" async defer></script>
  <script src="./js/s-cards.js" async defer></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Since its my first time asking question on SO i apologise in advance

Comment: You are using Jquery, why don't you use Ajax call to fetch all information and assign values dynamically

Comment: i don't actually know how to write js script. Since i recently started learning js and hence forth i don't know much about it Can you help me out

Comment: Which technologies you want to use in this project ?

Comment: technologies ? i didn't get that do you mean which library ? like jquery

Comment: You want to display information of logged in user, so how you are doing fetching information from database?

Comment: its for a web page

Comment: its the home page for my website so you can say its universal since ill regularly be updating the info and image i want it to be dynamic

Comment: You said you want to display information dynamically? So where the information is coming from ?

Comment: Let me explain you the flow, first of all create database in mysql, create a single table with fields you require. Then create document.ready function which will send Ajax call to your php page, in php page create connection to database and fetch information and return to ajax call, and then assign values to all fields as you already done above.

Comment: the information is from the json file and i don't actually want to use php for this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your entire program.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/homestyle.css"> -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/content.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-vp86vTRFVJgpjF9jiIGPEEqYqlDwgyBgEF109VFjmqGmIY/Y4HV4d3Gp2irVfcrp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <!-- CONTENT-->
  <section class="content">
    <div class="left-content">
      <div class="left-two">
        <section class="pt-5 pb-5">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6">
                <h3 class="mb-3">Carousel cards title </h3>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6 text-right">
                <a class="btn btn-dark mb-3 mr-1" href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-dark mb-3 " href="#carouselExampleIndicators2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <div id="row-one" class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci1" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct1" class="card-title">Image 1</h4>

                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci2" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct2" class="card-title">Image 2</h4>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci3" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct3" class="card-title">Image 3</h4>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci4" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct4" class="card-title">Image 4</h4>

                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci5" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct5" class="card-title">Image 5</h4>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci6" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct6" class="card-title">Image 6</h4>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci7" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct7" class="card-title">Image 7</h4>

                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci8" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct8" class="card-title">Image 8</h4>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                          <div class="card">
                            <img id="ci9" class="img-fluid" alt="100%x280">
                            <div class="card-body">
                              <h4 id="ct9" class="card-title">Image 9</h4>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-content"></div>
  </section>

  <!-- <script src="./myscript.js" async defer></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="./js/s-cards.js" async defer></script> -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>

  function myFunction(){
      var employees = '{ "employees" : [{ "title":"John" , "name":"Doe","src":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532763303805-529d595877c5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=5ee4fd5d19b40f93eadb21871757eda6" }, { "title":"Anna" , "name":"Smith", "src":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532715088550-62f09305f765?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ebadb044b374504ef8e81bdec4d0e840" }, { "title":"Peter" , "name":"Jones","src":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506197603052-3cc9c3a201bd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=0754ab085804ae8a3b562548e6b4aa2e" }, { "title":"Peter" , "name":"Jones","src":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532771098148-525cefe10c23?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=3f317c1f7a16116dec454fbc267dd8e4" }, { "title":"Peter" , "name":"Jones","src":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532715088550-62f09305f765?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ebadb044b374504ef8e81bdec4d0e840" }, { "title":"Peter" , "name":"Jones","src":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506197603052-3cc9c3a201bd?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=0754ab085804ae8a3b562548e6b4aa2e" }, { "title":"Peter" , "name":"Jones","src":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1507525428034-b723cf961d3e?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=ee8417f0ea2a50d53a12665820b54e23" }, { "title":"Peter" , "name":"Jones","src":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532777946373-b6783242f211?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=8ac55cf3a68785643998730839663129" }, { "title":"Peter" , "name":"Jones","src":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1532763303805-529d595877c5?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&amp;q=80&amp;fm=jpg&amp;crop=entropy&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;w=1080&amp;fit=max&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjMyMDc0fQ&amp;s=5ee4fd5d19b40f93eadb21871757eda6" } ]}';

      var obj = JSON.parse(employees);
      var j=0;
      for(var i=1;i<=9;i++){
        document.getElementById("ct"+i).innerHTML = obj.employees[j].title;
        document.getElementById("ci"+i).innerHTML = obj.employees[j].name;
        document.getElementById("ci"+i).src = obj.employees[j].src;
        console.log(obj.employees[j].src);
        j++;
      }


    };

    /*---Cards Homepage---*/

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this works exactly the way i intended it to work

Comment: Is there a way to do the same for image source i tried the for loop but it just won’t work

Comment: Yes we can, i have updated my answer, if it satisfies your question, accept and vote up for my answer.